# User friendly Navigation on Single page WebApp with several overlays

Tags: website-design, navigation, web-app, users

I am developing an angularjs App. There are lots of data entities ( eg photographers) displayed in a list. By clicking on one you get Detail data displayed in an overlay. There are links to other detail-overlays in there to. So you can navigate directly from a photographer Detail overlay to an photographer-institution Detail overlay and further on.

At some point the user will ask himself something like "how do I get back to the photographer Detail I opened first?". For now, it is possible to navigate back using the browsers back button. But that seems not obvious enuogh to me.

First I thought of something like a breadcrumb, which we used decades ago. As this seems a little oldfashioned and they could get very long too, I wondered if there are other ways solving this problem? Any patterns or working examples?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you already noticed the issue with no testing whatsoever. That means a lot. To the very least, that *you need to look for another approach*.

I'm not sure why the photographer's info opens in an overlay, but assuming there are good reasons to do it (and remember: *[you should always use overlays sparingly](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/overuse-of-overlays/)*) , you should NEVER connect overlays with other content in overlays, this is a very bad user experience.

To be honest, what you consider old fashioned is, without a doubt, your best option. However, depending on how these entities connect with each other, you may find other ways to do it, maybe even with a more original or modern look, but in order to do this, you'll need to define the [Information Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_architecture) for your site. The fact that you mention that *breadcrumbs could get very long* tells me the problem lies in IA rather than UI, so try putting it all in paper and see how it all connects in a logical way